# error: expected expression before 'createCharacter'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

so i am using presentmodalviewcontroller to change the active views in an ipad app. however when i try to change it using the statement `[self presentModalViewController:createCharacter animated:NO];` in an ibaction that is triggered by a button. however i get an error saying expected expression before 'createCharacter'. createCharacter is a custom view controller that  i have created... does anyone know what i am doing wrong? if you need any more relevant code just let me know,thanks

additional relevant code:

```
#import "createCharacter.h";


-(IBAction) buildCharacter{
    [self presentModalViewController:createCharacter animated:NO];      
}
```

createCharacter.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface createCharacter : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *view;
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you declared and initialized `createCharacter` either as a local var or an instance var?

Comment: Sounds like you have another variable/function/don't-know which is called createCharacter. If not, show some lines of code around the line you've shown.

Comment: i guess not...im still learning how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @the-kenny i did but the i changed the name of thefunction and i was still getting the error

Comment: First, try removing the ; from the #include. It's wrong there, but possibly not the source of your problem. If it still persists, show us createCharacter.h :)

Comment: okay removed the ';' nothing changed.. added createCharacter.h code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd love to see some code to look at, and without it maybe this advice will be wrong, BUT...in my experience I've always used IBActions with a single argument, and that argument has always been the sender, so something like tying a button press to `

```
-(IBAction) presentNewController:(id)sender`
```

where sender is the button that was pressed.

If you use a method like that to detect the button press from IB, then in code what you would want is something like:

```
// In your current view controller, the target where you wired up the button
-(IBAction) presentNewController:(id)sender
{
    if([sender isEqual:<whatever button you expect>])
    {
        CustomController *con = [[[CustomController alloc] init] autorelease];
        [selfpresentModalViewController:con animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that and it got rid of my error but now it crashes on launch  due to program received signal "sigabrt" and i get this warning: "Reciever 'createCharacter is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist"

Comment: This should work fine but be aware that the designated initialiser for View Controllers is -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;

Comment: Hey Joe, that forward declare warning means you need to import your class. So at the top of the file do #import "CustomController.h"

Comment: And of course Rog is right, make sure to use the correct initializer, I meant it more as an example of form :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate and initialise createCharacter before you can push it into the view.

Assuming createCharacter is a view controller:

```
createCharacter *customView = [[createCharacter alloc] initWithNibName:yourNibNameORnil bundle:yourBundleNameORnil];
[self presentModalViewController:customView animated:YES];
[customView release];
```

Comment: tried your code and it does the same thing as the previous answer...see my comment below

Comment: do you have a NIB file associated with this viewController? Can you please edit your question with how you are initialising it plus the init method in your view controller? I suspect you just need to connect your view to the view controller in the nib file via Interface Builder but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are sending a class to presentModalViewController:animated:. You need to initialize the class as Rog showed. As for MahatmaManic's answer, I have no idea why that was getting rid of your error. He is correct for OS X, but the argument is not required for iOS.

There are a few reasons you could still be getting the error after following Rog's example:

1. You have a variable named createCharacter, which means it was already initialized. In this case, change the name of your class to CreateCharacter. Classes are usually capitalized, and this would ensure that it is not confused with a variable.
2. The createCharacter header file is not properly imported. If you change the name of the file in XCode, it does not actually change the name of the file. If you try importing the file using the new name, it will not work.
3. Your initialization code wasn't right. In Rog's example, he used the default argument names. You should change `yourNibNameORnil` to the name of your NIB file, or nil if you are not using a NIB. You should also change `yourBundleNameORnil` to nil, assuming the NIB is located in your application's bundle. Here is an example assuming the NIB is in the application and named createCharacter.xib:

   createCharacter *customView = [[createCharacter alloc] initWithNibName:@"createCharacter" bundle:nil];